# How to get a court order for deceased relatives birth certificate?

Tags: canada, birth-certificate, court-order

What's the process for getting a court order in Canada for a deceased relatives birth certificate?

There is no will or executor of the will and the birth certificate is for genealogy purposes.

Comment: This varies by province, for example in BC, you can call 888-876-1633 (the [BC Vital Statistics Agency](https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/life-events/birth-adoption/births/birth-certificates)) and they will help guide you through the process. What province are you asking about?

Comment: Saskatchewan and BC. I called Saskatchewan vita stats and they said I need a court order as there is no executor of the will. No idea how to get a court order.

Comment: My strong instinct is that this is a case of miscommunication. Normally an executor of a will would not be required to get a birth certificate.

Comment: They said if the birth was more than 100 years ago then I can get the birth certificate no problem anyone can but because it wasn't then only the executor of the will can and since there is no will in my case I need a court order.